# Do we need to release block variable manually in dealloc method under Obj-C ARC mode?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, block

As you know interface vars don't need to be released (self.var = nil) manually in method  dealloc() in ARC mode, but how about block variable?  If block copy then do we also no need to release it? Have no idea on how to track block var memory leak by instrument.

Anyone who knows please share and thanks in advance.

Comment: no need to write release in ARC mode, and if you write release statement in file which have ARC mode, then it occurs error for that release statement.

Comment: self.var = nil (ARC mode) the same as [_var release];(None-ARC mode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[block copy]` is handled by ARC.

If you use `Block_copy` then you must use `Block_release`, but the above form is preferred with ARC.

Comment: Do you mean [block release] will be called implicitly in ARC mode? Thanks.

Comment: Yes - I'm too lazy to find the documentation now, but that's exactly what I read in the Apple docs when I was figuring out how to use `Block_copy` and `Block_release` -- and then realizing I didn't have to.

Answer (score 0):

you may need __weak you variable before put it to block to avoid retain cycle.

See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html for details.